# How to resolve InvalidTypeIdException when using @FeignClient?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a Spring Boot Library package `common-library`, within it contains a DTO class, say `OrderDTO` [package- `com.example.common.dto`].

I have two microservices - `Core` & `Notification` service. In `Core` service I have `Order` class in package `com.example.core.domain`.

In `Notification` service I added `common-library` external dependency and created a `@FeignClient` class

```
import com.example.common.dto.OrderDTO;

@FeignClient(name = "core")
public class CoreServiceClient {
  @GetMapping("/api/v1/order/get/{id})
  OrderDTO getOrderById(@PathVariable("id") String id);
}
```

Now when I call the `getOrderById` method from **Notification service**, I get the below error

```
InvalidTypeIdException: "Could not resolve type id 'com.example.core.domain.Order' as a subtype of `com.example.common.dto.OrderDTO`: no such class found"
```

Now I know one simple way to resolve this issue is by creating match class `Order` in package `com.example.core.domain`.

But I want to know if there are any workarounds without needing to create same class

Comment: No there is no workaround

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was adding **`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`** with `ObjectMapper` bean as constructor parameter

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper()));
}
```

Which was **serializing** the data type information in response. Removed the `objectMapper()`

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```